# PHP Array Efficiency?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I've been thinking about PHP's arrays efficiency lately. The fact that you can have both numeric and associative arrays in PHP of unlimited size makes me wonder how efficient they are to use. How would such a thing be implemented, exactly?

In Java and C, for example, you have to specify the array size and you do not have associative arrays (well, in Java, there are maps, but you get my point). Isn't that fact that there is no size limit on PHP arrays a serious memory concern? Doesn't this make PHP arrays "very expensive"?

Comment: PHP arrays are in fact hashtables (on C level). They have very little to do with arrays known from C or Java.

Comment: http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: Also http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

Comment: PHP does have a fixed array class if you really feel the need -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php